# WildFly 9.0.2 classloading issues

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, wildfly, wildfly-9

I am facing classloading issue in a WildFly server. I have deployed my EAR file in WildFly Standalone server. And declared dependencies through `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.

Everything seems to be working fine except this class:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:88)
```

I tried to solve this by adding `org.glassfish.javax.el` module to `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>      
            <module name="org.glassfish.javax.el" export= "TRUE"/>
            <module name="xxxxxxxx" export= "TRUE"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I also tried to solve by adding this to `global-modules` in configuration file. But still I am getting the same error.

```
<global-modules>
      <module name="org.glassfish.javax.el" slot="main"/>
</global-modules>
```

I tried to log classloading by enabling TRACE on `org.jboss.classloader` logger category but no luck.

Then I enabled classloading from JAVA_OPTS (`-verbose:class`) to console but this class is found in the log. In fact i didn't find many jars mentioned in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in the logs.

Could someone please help me to solve this issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you include the relevant parts of `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and what you tried in `global-modules`?

Comment: @TT. added relevant parts

Comment: You should not normally have to mess with `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` or `global-modules`. What is the original class loading problem that you were trying to solve?

Comment: @SteveC com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl class is the actual issue

Comment: Do you ever reference this class directly in your code? If not, have you included your own JSF implementation with your application (instead of using the one provided by WildFly)? ie. Do you have mojarra jars anywhere in your EAR?

Comment: @SteveC i do not have this class reference directly in my code. But i just included it in import statement. Still i am getting the same error. My application is not JSF implementation. It is just Servlet, JSP implementation. No mojarra jars are not present in my EAR

Comment: What about `el-impl` and/or `el-api` jars?

Comment: you have EAR deployment so you need to define dependencies for sub-deployments in jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Comment: try with below:

`<dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
          <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

you missed el-api dependency, you can add the following jar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then you met ClassNotFoundException:com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl , You missed el-impl jar

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```